# Why only meta appears when closing a question for migration?

Tags: support

When I try to click the "close button --> Off topic because --> This question belongs to another site in the Stack Exchange network" only meta appears as an option, am I doing it wrong, or do I lack reputation for such proposals ?

[image]

Comment: I swear this has been asked multiple times before, but I can't find the dupe.

Answer (score 4):

There aren't any migration paths in Arqade. Mod flag it asking it to be moved to another website.

Comment: For a bit more in-depth explanation, the major rule in migration is "Don't migrate crap". Migration isn't just of us to dump our crappy questions elsewhere, but to move good questions to their proper SE-site. We don't get enough questions for a wrong area for there to be a seperate path to them. Not good quality ones, at least. The few we do get, the mods can handle.